# How to keep TableLayout in Center using Android?

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

I have used dynamic width & height for the TableLayout and i have used the android:layout_gravity="center" but still my tablelayout remains in left side. I don't find any reason for it. please go through my below code.

**JAVA Code-:**

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    int width=0;

    int height=0;

    if(display.getWidth()<=240 && display.getHeight()<=400)
    {

        width = 200;

        height = 500;  

    }
    else
    {

        width=250;

        height=400;
    }


   TableLayout ab = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);

   ab.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));
```

**XML Code-:**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:id="@+id/tbl"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffcc">



 <TableRow>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_span="2">

    </TextView>         

</TableRow> 


<TableRow>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_span="2">

    </TextView>         

   </TableRow>
```

The two textview elements are aligned in the left margin. But i want it to be in the Center.

Please suggest me some good solution.!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving

```
android:gravity="center"
```

in your textviews